# joining two dictionaries and handling its common value

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi what if i wanted to do something with the common values instead of just updating them. For instance lets the say the value is a string and i wanted to put a simple tab between them

```
a={'car':'ferrari','color':'red','driver':'M'} 
b={'car':'lamborghini','color':'yellow','transmission':'manual'}
```

such that the result is,

```
merge_ab={'car':'ferrari\tlamborghini','color':'red\tyellow','driver':'M\t','transmission':'\tmanual'}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will work in Python 2.x:

```
{ k:a.get(k, '') + '\t' + b.get(k, '') for k in set(a.keys() + b.keys()) }

=> {'color': 'red\tyellow', 'car': 'ferrari\tlamborghini',
    'driver': 'M\t', 'transmission': '\tmanual'}
```

If you want to use iterators, do this in Python 2.x:

```
import itertools as it
{k:a.get(k,'')+'\t'+b.get(k,'') for k in set(it.chain(a.iterkeys(),b.iterkeys()))}
```

Equivalently, do this in Python 3.x:

```
{ k:a.get(k,'') + '\t' + b.get(k,'') for k in set(it.chain(a.keys(), b.keys())) }
```

Comment: You'll lose all items not in `a`.

Comment: This gives the exact output they wanted, but you can shorten the conditionals to `dicA.get(k, '')`.

Comment: @thg435 you're right, that's nicer. I updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: thank you so much I am using this. It seems quite elegant. Could you tell me if there would be any advantage in using iterkeys instead of keys or perhaps as pointed above perhaps viewkeys? Thank you

Comment: @user2755526 if this answer was the most helpful, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left ;) . Regarding your question: using `iterkeys()` is preferred in Python 2, because it won't create intermediate lists, only iterators. In Python 3 iterators are used by default, so `keys()` it's fine. Use iterators whenever possible!

Comment: @user2755526 I edited my answer to show how to use iterators, use the one appropriate for the version of Python in use

Comment: Hi Oscar, I am using 2.7 so i am using the first comprehension. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice Pythonic way to do it:

```
dicts = [a, b]
allKeys = set(k for d in dicts for k in d.iterkeys())
makeValue = lambda k: '\t'.join(d.get(k, '') for d in dicts) # Make merged value for a given key
merged = dict((k,makeValue(k)) for k in allKeys)
```

Comment: This has the benefit that it can merge more than two dicts - just add them to the list!

Answer (score 2):

You could merge the dicts first and then handle common keys separately:

```
merge_ab = dict(a, **b)
for key in set(a) & set(b):
    merge_ab[key] = '{0}\t{1}'.format(a[key], b[key])
```

If you are using Python 2.7 you can use the more efficient `a.viewkeys() & b.viewkeys()` instead of `set(a) & set(b)`.

Comment: ty, added it to my answer.

Comment: this appears to be the fastest of the methods suggested, for the input given at least.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Note that this modifies the dictionary `b` which might not be what you want; if you'd like to create a new dictionary, then just allocate one: `c={ }` and sort the items into it.

```
>>> a={'car':'ferrari','color':'red','driver':'M'}
>>> b={'car':'lamborghini','color':'yellow','transmission':'manual'}
>>> for k, v in a.items() : # Iterate over all key, item pairs of the a dictionary.
...     if k in b : # If a given key exists in the b dictionary as well, then...
...         b[k] += "\\" + v # ...merge the two items.
...     else : # Else, if the given key does not exist in the b dictionary, then...
...         b[k] = v # ...add it.
... 
>>> b
{'color': 'yellow\\red', 'car': 'lamborghini\\ferrari', 'transmission': 'manual', 'driver': 'M'}
```